# How to scope internal functions within a MAIN function?

Tags: r, function, oop, scope

My young son and I were playing a board game called Snails Pace.  Simple enough, so I sat down to show him the game on the R-console.

### Helper function

```
num.round = function(n, by=5)
    {
    byidx = (n %% by == 0); # these already are indexed well 
    new = by * as.integer((n + by) / by);
    res = n;
    res[!byidx] = new[!byidx];
    res;
    }
```

### Primary function

```
snails.pace = function(moves = 200, finish.line = 8,
                            snail.x = NULL,
                            snail.y = NULL,
                            snail.col = NULL
                        )
    {
    if(is.null(snail.x))    { snail.x = 0*(1:6); }
    if(is.null(snail.y))    { snail.y = 1*(1:6); }
    if(is.null(snail.col)) { snail.col = c("orange", "blue", "pink", "green", "yellow", "red"); }
    
    snail.rank = 0*snail.x; 
    crank = 1; # current rank   
    move.number = 0;
    
    snails.plot = function(snail.x, snail.y, snail.rank, move.number, moves, finish.line, crank) 
        { 
        xmax = max(10, max(snail.x) );
        ymax = max(8, max(snail.y) );
        plot(snail.x, snail.y, 
                col=snail.col, 
                pch=16, cex=5, 
                xlim=c(0, num.round(xmax, 5) ), 
                ylim=c(0, num.round(ymax, 4) ), 
                axes=FALSE, 
                frame.plot=FALSE, 
                xlab="", ylab="",
                main=paste0("Move #", move.number, " of ", moves)
                ); 
        #axis(gr.side("bottom")); 
        axis(1);
            has.rank = (snail.rank != 0);
            snails.lab = paste0(snail.x, "*", snail.rank);
            snails.lab[!has.rank] = snail.x[!has.rank];
        text(snail.x, y=snail.y, labels=snails.lab, col="black"); 
        abline(v = finish.line, col="gray", lty="dashed");
        }
    snails.update = function(snail.x, snail.y, snail.rank, move.number, moves, finish.line, crank) 
        {
        x = readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue, [ESC] to quit");
        n = sample(1:6, 1);
        snail.x[n] = 1 + snail.x[n];
        if( (snail.rank[n] == 0) && (snail.x[n] >= finish.line) )
            {           
            snail.rank[n] = crank;
            crank = 1 + crank;          
            # update to MAIN environment
            assign("snail.rank", snail.rank, envir=parent.frame() );
            assign("crank", crank, envir=parent.frame() );
            }       
        snail.x;
        }

    snails.plot(snail.x, snail.y, snail.rank, move.number, moves, finish.line, crank); 
    while(move.number < moves)
        {
        move.number = 1 + move.number;
        snail.x = snails.update(snail.x, snail.y, snail.rank, move.number, moves, finish.line, crank);
        snails.plot(snail.x, snail.y, snail.rank, move.number, moves, finish.line, crank);      
        }
    }
```

### Game play

```
snails.pace();
```

How to scope internal functions within MAIN environoment?

The MAIN function is `snails.pace()`.  You will notice in the internal function `snails.update`, I update two variables and assign them back to the MAIN scope using `assign`.

Is there a way at the MAIN level I can define all the variables and just USE them within all internal functions without having to assign them back or returning the updating values?

As you can see in my CODE, I call all of the variables into the functions and either "back assign" or return any changes.  I would prefer to just set a `new env()` or something and have MAIN work like R-Global seems to.  Any suggestions on how to do that?

That is, my internal functions would not pass anything in:  `snails.plot = function()` and `snails.update = function()` AS they would get the LOCAL environment variables (defined as within MAIN defined as `snails.pace()`).  And ideally update the LOCAL environment variables by updating the value within the internal function.

So it appears that I can drop the function passing.  See:

```
snails.pace2 = function(moves = 200, finish.line = 8,
                            snail.x = NULL,
                            snail.y = NULL,
                            snail.col = NULL
                        )
    {
    if(is.null(snail.x))    { snail.x = 0*(1:6); }
    if(is.null(snail.y))    { snail.y = 1*(1:6); }
    if(is.null(snail.col))  { snail.col = c("orange", "blue", "pink", "green", "yellow", "red"); }
    
    snail.rank = 0*snail.x; 
    crank = 1; # current rank   
    move.number = 0;
    
    snails.plot = function() 
        { 
        xmax = max(10, max(snail.x) );
        ymax = max(8, max(snail.y) );
        plot(snail.x, snail.y, 
                col=snail.col, 
                pch=16, cex=5, 
                xlim=c(0, num.round(xmax, 5) ), 
                ylim=c(0, num.round(ymax, 4) ), 
                axes=FALSE, 
                frame.plot=FALSE, 
                xlab="", ylab="",
                main=paste0("Move #", move.number, " of ", moves)
                ); 
        #axis(gr.side("bottom")); 
        axis(1);
            has.rank = (snail.rank != 0);
            snails.lab = paste0(snail.x, "*", snail.rank);
            snails.lab[!has.rank] = snail.x[!has.rank];
        text(snail.x, y=snail.y, labels=snails.lab, col="black"); 
        abline(v = finish.line, col="gray", lty="dashed");
        }
    snails.update = function() 
        {
        x = readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue, [ESC] to quit");
        n = sample(1:6, 1);
        snail.x[n] = 1 + snail.x[n];
        if( (snail.rank[n] == 0) && (snail.x[n] >= finish.line) )
            {           
            snail.rank[n] = crank;
            crank = 1 + crank;          
            # update to MAIN environment
            assign("snail.rank", snail.rank, envir=parent.frame() );
            assign("crank", crank, envir=parent.frame() );
            }       
        snail.x;
        }

    snails.plot(); 
    while(move.number < moves)
        {
        move.number = 1 + move.number;
        snail.x = snails.update();
        snails.plot();      
        }
    }
```

@MrFlick is correct about the lexical scoping, if I understand the above correctly.  If an internal updates something from MAIN, it has to assign it back to MAIN I guess `<<-` or `assign ... parent`.  Is there not a way to tell the internal SUBFUNCTIONS to SCOPE at the same level of MAIN?

Comment: Unrelated, but it would be more idiomatic to not set `NULL` as the default value for your function args. If you want custom behavior when the user does not specify them, you can use `if(missing(snail.x))`. But in this case you seem to be checking if they are `NULL` to set default values, which could be done by setting `snail.x = 0*(1:6)` instead of `snail.x = NULL` in the argument definition.

Comment: You could use `snail.rank <<- snail.rank` rather than `assign()`. The `<<-` will assign the variable by looking at the parent scopes till it find's a matching variable name. But generally when working with a functional language, it's best to try to avoid calling functions with side effects that modify variables outside the function scope.

Comment: @MrFlick That is the goal.  Keep everything SCOPED inside the MAIN function without passing ALL the variables to the internal functions every time.

Comment: You don't have to pass the variables to the function. Because R uses lexical scoping, the function will have access to the variables in the scope where it was defined. It's just you need to use `<<-` to update those values rather than `<-`. That's just how R variables work.

Comment: @MrFlick Isn't `<<-` sloppy compared to `assign ... parent` which is more precise.  Doesn't `<<-` search all the way up the SCOPE environment tree?  This is what I am doing `assign("snail.rank", snail.rank, envir=parent.frame() );`

Comment: Yes. `<<-` is sloppy. If you want to be explicit, use `assign()` as you've already done. There's no other way to limit variable scope in R. If you want to change the rules how variables work, you'll need to design your own programming language I'm afraid. If you were to move this all to a package you'd have your own namespace that you could use as your "main" environment. Or if you don't like the functional paradigm, you can use an object oriented frame work like S4 or the new R7 package.

Answer (score 2):

To have a function `f` defined within another function `main` such that `f` has the same scope as `main` surround the entire body of `f` with `eval.parent(substitute({...}))` like this:

```
main <- function() {
  f <- function() eval.parent(substitute({
    a <- a + 1
    b <- 0.5
  }))

  a <- 1
  f()
  f()
  10 * a + b
}

main()
## [1] 30.5
```

The gtools package has `defmacro` which allows the same thing and uses the same technique internally.  Also see the wrapr package.

Comment: I like where this "MACRO" thought is heading.  `eval.parent(substitute(` is an interesting wrapper.  I need to think about it some more.

Answer (score 2):

There are two completely different concepts called "parent" in R:  the `parent.frame()` of a call, and the `parent.env()` of an environment.

`parent.frame()` walks up the chain of the stack of calls.  If you have a recursive function that calls itself, it will appear multiple times in that chain.

In general, it's dangerous to use `parent.frame()`, because even if the context in which you use it now makes it clear which environment will be the `parent.frame()`, at some future time you might change your program (e.g. make the internal function into a recursive one, or call it from another internal function), and then `parent.frame()` will refer to something different.

The `parent.env()` function applies to an environment; `parent.env(environment())` gives you the enclosing environment of the current one.  If you call `parent.env(environment())` it will *always* refer to the environment where your current function was defined.  It doesn't matter how you called it, just how you defined it.  So you always know what will happen if you assign there, and it's much safer in the long term than using `parent.frame()`.

The `<<-` "super-assignment" works with enclosing environments, not the stack of calls.  If you do `var <<- value`, then as long as you are sure that `var` was defined in the enclosing function, you can be sure that's what gets modified.

One flaw in R is that it doesn't enforce the existence of `var` there, so that's why some people say `<<-` is "sloppy".  If you accidentally forget to define it properly, or spell it wrong, R will search back through the whole chain of environments to try to do what you asked, and if it never finds a matching variable, it will do the assignment in the global environment.  You almost never want to do that:  keep side effects minimal.

So, to answer the question "Is there a way at the MAIN level I can define all the variables and just USE them within all internal functions without having to assign them back or returning the updating values?":  as you found in your edit, the nested function can read the value of any variable in the MAIN function without requiring any special code.  To modify those variables, be sure both `snail.rank` and `crank` are defined in MAIN, then use `<<-` in the nested function to assign new values to them.

Comment: So if I think `<<-` is sloppy and don't want to use it, you are saying use `parent.env(environment())` instead of `parent.frame()` for my `assign` back?  You are saying `parent.frame()` may also be called by some as sloppy?

Comment: Yes to the first.  That has the advantage that it doesn't depend on remembering to create the variable first, as `<<-` does.  For the second question, I'd say "potentially dangerous" rather than "sloppy".